# In a jar there are 19 red jelly beans and 10 green jelly beans. In how many ways can you pick 4 red jelly beans and 4 green jelly beans?

Tags: combinations

In a jar there are 19 red jelly beans and 10 green jelly beans. In how many ways can you pick 4 red jelly beans and 4 green jelly beans?

Comment: Are we picking a total of 8 jelly beans?

Comment: Yes, you are picking 8 jelly beans. The answer is supposedly 813, 960 though I can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ${19 \choose 4}$ ways to pick 4 red jelly beans and $ {10 \choose 4}$ ways to pick 4 green jelly beans. Hence,

$${19 \choose 4}{10 \choose 4} = 813960.$$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!